# How to set the size and background of splash screen for universal app

Tags: iphone, ipad

I am using Default.png for iPhone and Default-Landscape.png for ipad. But in case of ipad the splash screen shows only half of the image and rest is cut. It seems to be the size of image becomes double of what it should be. I am using image with width:525 and height:175 for ipad.

I also added:

```
UILaunchImageFile~ipad  Default-Landscape.png
```

in my info.plist file. What might be the problem? Please guide me....

Also can i set the backgroung of splash screen to white????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The landscape iPad launch image *has* to be 1024x748 pixels. That's the only size that will prevent your image from scaling.
I guess the iPad tries to scale your image to a height of 748 which means the width will be 2244px. Not exactly double but something like four times the size of what you want.

Create a white image with dimensions of 1024x748 and put your 525x175 image in the middle of it.

Answer (score 0):

Try the image name `Default@2x.png` and size would be `1024X768`....

Comment: @2x is an image suffix for the **iphone** retina screen. And you got the iPad image size wrong too.

Comment: Yes. I got greater size of image for iPad split screen